# Cerrar pagina web JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un proceso que abre una pagina web.

```js
<script>
  function Abrir() {
  miPopup = window.open("PopUp.asp", "miventana",   "width=500,height=250,menubar=no")
  } 
  </script>
```

Al tener la pagina web abierta hace una pregunta la cual dice, quiere realizar los cambios ? y aparece un boton de aceptar y otro para cancelar.

Necesito que al dar click en el boton de cancelar cierre la pagina web PopUp.asp

Comment: En necesario hacer eso con un popup , lo que quieres hacer, no te sirve tener esa parte en un modal? , o es mucho lo que tienes que hacer?

Comment: No conocia ese objeto, me sirvio mucho mejor que abrir una nueva pagina web

Comment: de nada estimado, siempre se aprenden cosas nuevas. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Una de las formas de cerrar una pagina web utilizando JavaScript es de esta manera

```
<input type="submit" value="Cancelar" onclick="javascript:window.close()">
```

Comment: Aunque debes especificar que solo puede cerrar ventas creadas por `Javascript` pues no te va a dejar cerrar el resto.